# Resizing Icon of MenuItems in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to resize the icon of the menu and menuitems  in WPF C#

I have done following

```
<DockPanel>
        <Menu Background="CadetBlue" Height="53" Width="500" IsMainMenu="True"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Padding="40,0,0,0" Header="File" Foreground="#FF383131" FontSize="20" Background="Beige" Width="100" Height="50" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/WPFMenuItem;component/Images/garden.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                <MenuItem Header="New" FontSize="20">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/WPFMenuItem;component/Images/garden.jpg" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Exit" FontSize="20">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/WPFMenuItem;component/Images/ic_launch_man.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

            </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
        <TextBox />
    </DockPanel>
```

I have increased width,height and margin but did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a render transform and set the X and Y scale.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Image Source="/WPFMenuItem;component/Images/garden.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform X="2" Y="3.7"/>             
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: Hopefully that's more helpful.

Comment: Actually, you probably don't need the TransformGroup if you only have one transform.